# c# system.net.FileWebRequest Access denied error

Tags: c#, system.net

I want to get a file size  over network via System.Net.FileWebRequest.  For example: \IP\c$\sampleFile.txt

I supply the credentials for accessing file via passing it to FilewebRequest's credentials
but the code below returns an access to path denied error.  What is worng here?
How can I access files over network? (I have crediantals to access file)

```
 System.Net.FileWebRequest request = (System.Net.FileWebRequest)
 System.Net.FileWebRequest.Create(url);
 request.PreAuthenticate = true;
 request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_clientUser,_clientPass);
 FileWebResponse response = (System.Net.FileWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

 // gets the size of the file in bytes    
 Int64 iSize = response.ContentLength;
 response.Close();
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the file you are trying to get is on your network rather than through an http call which is what FileWebRequest is for.

Try:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
long fileBytes = fileInfo.Length;
long fileKBytes = fileInfo.Length / 1024;
```

The filepath being your \IP\c$\sampleFile.txt. Make sure it is accessible by your machine to read.

Comment: The problem is here that.I have crediantials to access file (username and pass)If first I try to access file over run>command "\\IP\c$\sampleFile.txt" windows  opens authenticate windows and than using code gives no error..but i have to succeed the authentication in code also...